# HashMap with ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have a java question about a HashMap with an ArrayList in it. The key is a string and the value is the ArrayList (`HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>`)

I am given a list of multiple keys and I need to put the corresponding values into the ArrayList, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's an example:

(What I am given)

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
123
123
```

The keys are actually file names so the file is the value for the ArrayList. Now I have to separate those filenames so i can add the files to the ArrayList. Does this make sense?

This is the only code I have:

```
Set<String> tempModels = Utils.getSettingSet("module_names", new HashSet<String>(), getActivity());
        for(String s : tempModels) {
            Log.d("Loading from shared preferences: ", s);
            String key = s.substring(0, 17);

        }
```

Comment: `map.get(key).add(value)` check for null

Comment: the hashmap is empty to begin with though

Comment: if you get null value then create an array list and add value to it and then use `put()`

Comment: *the hashmap is empty to begin with though* can't see it, where is it though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this,

```
List<Object> al = map.get(key);
if (al == null) {
  al = new ArrayList<Object>();
  map.put(key, al);
}
al.add(value);
```

Please note that the above uses raw `Object` Lists. You should (if possible) pick a proper type, and use it.

**Edit**

Some prefer the (slightly shorter) form,

```
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
  map.put(key, new ArrayList<Object>());
}
map.get(key).add(value);
```

Comment: There is no way `key` could be null, actually the whole validation on the `key` seems unnecessary. Also, `HashMap` does allow null key.

Comment: use `containsKey()` that is better than checking value as `null`.

Comment: @BheshGurung Agreed. Edited.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I you like any comment then it's a good practice to up-vote it. Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you very much! I implemented it and it worked!

Comment: @user3218114 Define "better". While that form is shorter, it requires performing the map look up 1 extra time. I certainly do not consider it "better".

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use for a guava Multimap, which manages the existence/creation of the inner List.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html